# "Confirmed that..." vs "Confirmed to have..."

Tags: grammar

My dad asked me if the following sentence was grammatically correct:

> Chris confirmed to have modified the PLC tag.

To me, the "to have" part seemed incorrect. I thought the sentence would have to be written something along the lines of this:

> Chris confirmed that he had modified the PLC tag.

In response to this, my dad argued that similar to how you could say "Chris promised that he would do something", and "Chris promised to do something", you should also be able to say "Chris confirmed that he had done something", and "Chris confirmed to have done something".

Is this correct, and if not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The *confirmed to have* phrasing is awkward, and if I heard or read it I would have difficulty understanding the meaning.

The comparison with *promise to* is interesting.  I tried various other verbs in these sentences, like *said, agreed, denied, doubted*.  In all of the cases I thought of, the *... to have done ...* phrasing sounds wrong, while *... that he had ...* sounds right.  But actually that's true of *promise* as well, if you use the same tense: *promised that he had done something* works, but *promised to have done something* does not.

So one response to your father's argument is that the *to have done* construction just isn't correct, even for *promise*.

But that isn't the whole story, because even if we switch to the tense where *promised to* works, most other verbs still don't sound right in that phrasing.  *Agreed* is the only one I came up with that works this way:  *Chris agreed to modify the PLC tag* is just fine, but *Chris denied to modify the PLC tag* is not.

There may be some linguistic explanation for this, but I'm not aware of it.  I'd just say that for certain verbs the *to do something* has developed as an acceptable idiom, but for most it is not right.

(But in another context ... *Chris confirmed to have modified the PLC tag* would be perfectly understandable as a newspaper headline.  In this case I would interpret it as *Someone has confirmed that Chris modified the PLC tag*, so it has a different meaning than in your example.  This relies on syntactical idioms used in headline writing.)

Comment: Past-participial "confirmed to have X" is perfectly standard and the Corpus of Contemporary American English has many examples including from the New York Times "So far, at least three people are confirmed to have died", ABC News (US) "Mack is the only one confirmed to have stayed with NXIVM long term", Business Insider "At least six people were confirmed to have died in their cars while attempting to flee." army.mil "To date, 120 active-duty Soldiers are confirmed to have taken their lives" (The OP's example is in note form and omits "is").

Comment: @StuartF Those are all passive uses, not active as in the OP's example.  If the sentence was "Chris was confirmed to have modified the PLC tag", I would agree that it's standard usage.  But that would mean somebody else confirmed it.

Answer (score 1):

When **confirmed** is used adjectivally it is complemented by the infinitival clause:

> The patients in the study were confirmed to have taken the medication at the correct dosage.

When used verbally, **confirmed** is complemented by the declarative clause:

> Trained hospital staff confirmed that all patients in the study had taken the correct dosage of the medication.

Compare:

> They say that it took 300 years to build.
>
> It is said to have taken 300 years to build.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is trying to say "They confirmed" without he/she/them.  That is the challenge in light of expectations now placed on gender.  In the business world, it is safer to avoid those pronouns.

Struggling with this verbiage without using pronouns:
For self-employed borrowers, **the signer confirms** to have verified that the business is open, active, and operational at the time of this verification.

So, your father's suggestions are good.

Also: Chris confirmed [to have] **modifying** the PLC tag.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/454009)